# Why my sql query isn't working even the query is correct?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax

[working query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtRyw.png)

[non-working query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrM4l.png)
The first query:

```
INSERT INTO `data` (`id`, `data`)
    VALUES (NULL, 'more data'); (working)
```

And the second:

```
INSERT INTO 'data' ('id', 'data')
    VALUES (NULL, 'more data'); (non-working)
```

Please tell me what is the difference between them cause I learn to use single quote(') for query in school instead of back tick? (`), is it a new feature or is it always what it is?

Comment: You have single quotes around column names in the second query.  I vote to close such questions as a typographical error.  Single quotes should *only* be used for string and date constants.  If you learned otherwise, you learned bad practices.

Comment: The difference is that you learned standard SQL, while MySQL was written for people who don't really care about the standard and just want something close enough that works.